# Where is the yellow triangle in the Moonstone level?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

How do you get the yellow triangle in the Moonstone level of the Trials mode?  I can't seem to find it.  All I can see is the glowing arrows that show right, right, down.  I tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you feel one of these answers is sufficient, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

In Moonstone III, you have to take the bomb arrows from the chest and shoot them into the purple glass (into, not through) on the left of the spawn point. This will cause the glass to blow up. From here, you go to the left and jump into the ceiling. It's in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's in Moonstone III.  Get the bomb arrows and carefully shoot an arrow through the left purple wall and have it land next to the right purple wall in the center of the map.  It will blow up and then you can go into that area and it's up and to the left.